# Return Nested Json from database as an array with Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have this nested json in my database

```
 {

"skills":{
    "skill1":{
        "description":"deal 100 damage",
        "cost":2,
        "name":"basic skill"
    },
        "skill2":{
        "description":"deal 900 damage",
        "cost":1,
        "name":"special skill"
    }
}
}
```

but when i get this json from my database , its returning a string (image1)

[image: image1]
 im using laravel to get the data from the database .

```
 public function list(){
        $data = Cd::all();
        return $data;  
  }
```

and i want this json to be like in postman preview (image2),  an array so i can access its properties ,

example: after a foreach I can access "skill1->description" , cost ,etc.

How can i do that ?

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Cd Model you should cast your 'skills' attribute:

```
class Cd extends Model 
{
 protected $casts = ['skills'=>'array'];
.... 
}
```

by using '$casts'  your model will automatically convert the json field into string instead of pure string

more about array & json casting in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: will try !, should i migrate  after doing this ?

Comment: no, this code will make the wanted result without the need to migrate